# No module named... Issue

Tags: python

Hi so i'm trying to get started on machine learning by installing tensorflow, however it's only supported by `Python 3.6.x` as of now.

I guess you can say this was a failed attempt to downgrade python.

My installed version of python is `3.7.2` which has all my modules installed.

I just installed `Python 3.6.8`.

The IDE i use is `Visual Studio Code`

However now when i use `Python 3.7.2` in `Visual Studio Code`, I get an error saying no module named... was found

Comment: So... what exactly is your error? Please give more information (Error message, code which gives error, etc.).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info. Currently I have 3.6.8 and 3.7.2 installed. The 3.7.2 has all my modules installed. After I installed 3.6.8, I couldn't use the modules in 3.7.2

Comment: If you are using Windows, try repairing `Python 3.7.2` with the installer. Also try reinstalling the packages.

Answer (score 1):

You must install it. Type this in cmd:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow is not suport by python 3.7 its only supported by 3.6 use a virtual environment to deal with multiple python versions.